# Align input to left in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have div with 2 divs in it

In one div is text, in second input

Here is code

```
<div id="main-info" style="margin-top: 30px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 blue-text">
      Diffuculty of investigation
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <input class="form-control"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #1f66b4;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  background-image: none;     
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
```

I have View like this
[image]

But I need to make it like this
[image]

So input will be closer to text.

How I need to rewrite code?

Comment: The html and css code would really help us help you out.

Comment: Updated my post @AngelosChalaris

Comment: Go and study the framework your are using. This is basic and easy to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="xs-hidden col-md-2 "></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 blue-text">
    Diffuculty of investigation
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 ">
    <input class="form-control"/>
  </div>
  <div class="xs-hidden col-md-2 "></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It moves it a little bit, but not that I need

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.